# Transform NextJs output into JSON using ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

For migration purposes I have to transform the content generated by nextjs into JSON format like `{content: "generated markup"}` in expressjs.

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = 8080;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const nextApp = next({dev});
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.all('*', async (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.use((req, res, next) => {
        /* How to set res.json({content:<RESULT_FROM_NEXT_JS>})??? */
    });

    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

What I understand so far is that next creates a stream of chucked data but I do not know how to block this stream to then create a json from it. Any clue on how to build a middleware for that? Or any other idea on how to generate a JSON in this format?